# AWS lambda function from deployment not updating, Elemental MediaConvert on-demand video encoding

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-media-convert

I followed this below guide which worked perfectly apart from having to update the stack to use node 12 instead of 8.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/serverless-video-on-demand-vod-workflow/

It takes an uploaded video file from an S3 bucket and runs it through the AWS media converter and outputs HLS video files for on-demand videos.

**Issue:**
The lambda function converts the file into 6 different bitrates, I only want 3. So I went into the lambda function and edited the config file so there are only 3 presets not 6.

Yet when I encode more videos it is always producing all 6 presets.

It's as if the lambda file is not saving, or more likely I'm not understanding how the whole process works.

How do I get this to only encode 3 HLS bitrates?

Answer (score 0):

You have to go to AWS mediaconvert console. Once there, go to job templates. There's should be 3, one for 2160p source files, and two more, one for 1080p and 720p. You have to go into each one and you'll see a list of outputs. You should see HLS with 6 outputs. Click on HLS and at the top of the page, click update, then you can remove the unwanted outputs. You should click export JSON at the top of the page just incase you make a mistake and want to roll back without deploying the whole stack again.